# list of ADR's by volume or market cap

Tags: market-data, data-mining

I'm looking for a list of ADR's (for a simulation) that I can screen by either market cap or volume?

If anyone knows of a free way to get such a list it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have Internet and can use it OK (maybe not, in some countries it doesn't always work), if you look up ADR or American Depository Receipt you will find "Listing of ADRs". This will take you to, for example, http://adrs.net/directory.htm  There you will be able to see a list of all ADRs by their country of origin. With the names & symbols from this list, you can look up the latest values of individual market cap & volume on any of the financial sites, for example, Yahoo Finance, http://finance.yahoo.com/  For stock screeners, go to an Internet search engine and type in "Stock Screener". You will find plenty of them.